# Show that $\phi(z) = i\frac{1-z}{1+z}$ is bijection between the open disk and upper half plane

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

How do I show that $\phi(z) = i\frac{1-z}{1+z}$ is a bijection $\phi: D \to \mathbb{H}$ between the open disk $D = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| < 1 \}$ and the upper half plane $\mathbb{H} = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : \text{Im} z > 0 \}$?

If I understand the question correctly, showing $\phi$ is both surjective and injective tells me nothing about whether there is a bijection between the specified sets? And the same holds for finding an explicit inverse?

I think I am not understanding how to approach a question like this, it's the first of its kind for me. And I am also not understanding how to think about it. Perhaps I am missing some basic prior knowledge.

Comment: What is $q{}{}$?

Comment: Oops that is a typo. q = 1

Comment: bijective means surjective and injective

Comment: Look up Möbius transformations. Thay map 'circles' into 'circles' (lines are circles on the Riemann sphere). Plus they preserve an orientation of sorts. Note that $\phi(0) = i$, $\phi(1) = 0$ and $\phi(\infty) = -i$.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner perhaps you could elaborate on why showing it is surjective and injective is enough to show there is a bijection between $D$ and $\mathbb{H}$?

Comment: $\phi$ is a bijection **iff** it is surjective and injective.

Comment: I know that, but I don't understand why doing some algebraic manipulations tells me something about a bijection about $D$ and $\mathbb{H}$? So I am not understanding something

Comment: Are you familiar with Möbius transformations?

Comment: No, is it necessary to solve the question? It was not in the lecture/course material

Comment: No, not necessary, perhaps it is meant as preparatory material. By solving $w=\phi(z)$ for $z$ you can find an explicit inverse function. If you can show that $\phi$ maps $\mathbb{H}$ onto $D$ then you are finished.

Comment: I think there may be a fundamental misunderstanding going on. You say that you don't know why showing phi is both surjective and injective will say anything about the sets being bijective. But, this is precisely what it means for there to be a bijection between the two sets.

Comment: Beware, I confused the direction is my comments above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if we solve $w=\phi(z) = i {1-z \over 1+z} $ formally then we get $z = {i-w \over i+w}$.

Note that $-1$ in the domain and $-i$ in the range (codomain) are special. If we try to solve $\phi(z) = -i$ we get $1=-1$ hence the range of $\phi$ does not include $-i$. 
In particular, it shows that $\phi$ is a bijection $\phi: \mathbb{C} \setminus \{ -1\} \to \mathbb{C} \setminus \{ -i\}$. (As an aside, as a map on the Riemann sphere, $\phi: C_\infty \to C_\infty$ is a bijection and $\phi(-1) = -i$.)

Hence if we can show that $\phi(D) = \mathbb{H}$ we are finished.

(Note that $-1 \notin D$ and $-i \notin \mathbb{H}$.)

We have $\phi(x+iy) = i{1-x-iy \over 1+x+iy} = i{(1-x-iy) (1+x-iy) \over (1+x)^2+y^2} = i{1-x^2-y^2 -2 iy \over (1+x)^2+y^2} = {-2y +i(1-x^2-y^2) \over (1+x)^2+y^2}$.

Hence we see that $\operatorname{im} \phi(x+iy)>0 $ **iff**  $x^2+y^2 < 1$.

Comment: I don't understand how this shows surjectivity. From my understanding, this just shows that $\phi$ maps the unit disk to a subset of the upper half plane.

Comment: @IAAW Since it is a Möbius transformation, the map $\phi: \mathbb{C} \setminus \{ -1\} \to \mathbb{C} \setminus \{ -i\}$ is a bijection. Since $\phi(D) = \mathbb{H}$, it follows that it is a bijection and hence surjective.

Comment: Yes, but precisely why is $\phi(D) = \mathbb{H}$? It seems you have only showed that $\phi(D)\subseteq\mathbb{H}$.

Comment: Read the last line of the answer. Keep in mind that $\phi$ is a bijection (either with the relevant points removed, or as a Riemann sphere map). So every point in $\mathbb{H}$ has some corresponding point in $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{ -1\}$ and the above shows that it is, in fact, in $D$.

Answer (score 0):

It's a Mobius transformation that takes $1,-1,i$ to $0,\infty,1$ respectively.  Thus it takes the unit circle to the real line.

Then use a test point, say $0$.  It goes to $i$.  As in the comments, look up Mobius transformation to see that we are done.